# Angular material custom responsive priority horizontal toolbar calculation

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have write a customize angular material priority horizontal toolbar but it not work as I expected. When resize into smaller screen, the icon will move to the more popout list

However I facing the problem where icon will keep flasing when resize the browser screen. And it wont auto resize on the first load. I'm refer the similar concept on this jquery version. https://codepen.io/Dreamdealer/pen/waVzmK

```
$(window).on('resize load',function(){
  calcWidth();
});
```

[image]

[image]

Below is my angular material project demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2fmjnq?file=src/app/toolbar-overview-example.ts

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're either adding or removing an icon from the toolbar when the window is resized.  This is not necessarily the case, in fact since for every resized pixel an event is fired most of the resize events shouldn't modify the icons.

The easiest way to fix this is by making the remove item call conditional:

```
if (this.currentToolbarWidth < this.currentSpaceUsed) {
  this.addItemToPopup();
} else if (this.currentSpaceUsed + 64 < this.currentToolbarWidth && this.popupListItems.length) {
  this.removeItemFromPopup();
}
```

Note the hardcoded 64px, which is the size of an icon. You might want to change this by calculating to the width of the first icon or something similar.

Comment: understand, any idea on how to fit the button based on the initiall width of mat-toolbar when first open screen

Comment: This can be solved in multiple ways. The current issue is you're only able to add or remove a single icon and the adjustToolBar method is only called once. So, you could create a while loop which keeps repeating itself until no icon is added or removed. But it would be cleaner and more efficient to calculate the initial space used based on the toolbar size.